# I'm having trouble creating a feed like this

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm developing an app using ionic framework 2 but i'm having trouble creating a list of posts like this one (already got the code done but can't style the list)

Can anyone help me ?
Thats what i have atm

```
<ion-list no-lines>
<ion-item *ngFor="let post of data">
  <div class="wrapper" style="background: url({{post.imgUrl}});
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;">
    <p>{{post.imgUrl}}</p>
    <p>{{post.title.rendered}}</p>
  </div>

</ion-item>


.feed .wrapper p {
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(30,87,153,0) 0%, rgba(0,22,177,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(30,87,153,0) 0%, rgba(0,22,177,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(rgba(30,87,153,0) 0%, rgba(0,22,177,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */ /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */ /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#001e5799', endColorstr='#0016b1',GradientType=0 );
bottom: 0;
color: white;
font-family: Roboto;
font-size: 1.25em;
left: 0;
padding: 0.25em 0.75em;
position: absolute;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
top: 75%;
line-height: 120px;
```

}

[Uefa euro 2016 app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoMq1.png)

Comment: Have you tried with Ionic Card CSS components http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#cards ?

Comment: That was exactly what i was looking for. Thank you :)

Comment: I'm glad it's helpful, I'll put this as an answer to be visible to others if they have the same question. If my answer helped solve the problem you may select it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you can use **[Ionic Card CSS components](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#cards)**.

> Cards have become widely used in recent years. They are a great way to
>   contain and organize information, while also setting up predictable
>   expectations for the user.  Cards make it easy to display the same
>   information visually across many different screen sizes. They allow
>   for more control, are flexible, and can even be animated. Cards are
>   usually placed on top of one another, but they can also be used like a
>   "page" and swiped between, left and right.

Images can be combined with lists and other elements.

```
<div class="list card">

  <div class="item item-avatar">
    <img src="avatar.jpg">
    <h2>Pretty Hate Machine</h2>
    <p>Nine Inch Nails</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item item-image">
    <img src="cover.jpg">
  </div>

  <a class="item item-icon-left assertive" href="#">
    <i class="icon ion-music-note"></i>
    Start listening
  </a>

</div>
```